# Metafunction for expressing "dominance" of one sequence over another

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I'm seeking a single meta-function (such as `std::less_equal`) that can be used or combined in order to express a dominance relationship, defined as follows.

Sequence A dominates another sequence B (both of having equal length) if:

1. Each element of A is not less than the corresponding element B
2. At least one element of A is greater than the corresponding element of B

So far the best that I have been able to come up with consists of two separate tests one after the other as follows.

```
template<typename T>
bool dominates( T& sequence1 , T& sequence2 )
{
    if( std::equal( sequence1.begin() , sequence1.end() , sequence2.begin() ) ) return false;
    return std::equal( sequence1.begin() , sequence1.end() , sequence2.begin() , std::less_equal<double>() );
}
```

Is it possible do the same using a single metafunction?

Comment: This isn't a metafunction.

Comment: I know. `std::less_equal` is though.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, you want a more optimal version of the code you present? Just simply unroll the loop STL would generate for you and merge the two operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with one-pass code is that you have to keep the state - you have to remember whether you encountered the dominating element or not.

Writing a simple `for` loop would give you an advantage of short-circuiting when you know that the result is `false`. But if you want a one-liner, here you go:

```
template<typename T>
bool dominates2(const T& sequence1, const T& sequence2) {
    return std::inner_product(std::begin(sequence1), std::end(sequence1),
        std::begin(sequence2), 0,
        // this accumulates the result
        [](int prevCmp, int curCmp){ return prevCmp > 0 ? prevCmp : (curCmp > 0 ? curCmp : prevCmp + curCmp); },
        // this compares corresponding elements of ranges
        [](const auto& a1, const auto& a2){ return (a1 > a2) - (a2 > a1); }) < 0;
}
```